# FormClosing() event loaded twice

Tags: c#, formclosing

I want to show a MessageBox to confirm the exiting before letting a form close.  So, a FormClosing event is created.

```
  private void Form_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
     //nothing here for now
  }
```

I have the MessageBox shown twice.  Debugging tool shows that somehow the code goes over FormClosing() twice.  That happens even when I have nothing inside FormClosing() as above.  I did search for FormClosing() in my entire code, and there is only one place where it is subscribed to.  I have the same FormClosing() in two other projects, and that does not happen.  Can anyone give me a pointer?  This is not making any sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the solution?

Comment: What does`stack trace say abot how it got there?

Comment: Can you pls post your code. If not code, then the skeleton at least ?

Comment: I  have rebuilt it.  Samething happens.  It keeps going over FormClosing() twice.  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I do not know how to use strack trace.

Comment: Search for `Form_Main_FormClosing` to check if it is twice subscribed.

Comment: If you are trying to exit out of the application on this event, then you should unsubscribe to this event handler before Application.Exit() statement. This is because the Application.Exit() function fires the FormClosing event once again.

Answer (score 4):

You mustn't call the either Close and Dispose methods in the FormClosing event handler

The form closing code should be:

```
private void Form_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
     DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("EXIT?", "Exit Program", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

     if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
     {
          e.Cancel = true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Dispose doesn't call FormClosing I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely 'guess' is that you are subscribing to the event twice.  Remember to check the auto-generated designer code if you are using the Designer.

If you set a BreakPoint on the event - you can also pull up the Call Stack (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx - Debug / Window / Call Stack) and you can see what code was executed to get to where you are.

It's entirely possible to call an event handler directly (but probably unlikely that you'd do it by mistake); but looking at the call stack can help track it down.

Finally - make sure you aren't calling `Application.Exit` or similar while handling the Closing event - I believe that can trigger a second firing.

Comment: OK,
To make things easier, I uploaded my code here:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3dcu0IKtxKxblRudlhVOE1rZWM


When I use This.Dispose(), it loads twice.  When I use This.Close(), IT NEVER CLOSES.

Right now this mystery is scaring the hell outta me.  Never happened before.  I had two other Form Apps with the same method, and they worked fine.  HELP!!!!!!!!  Ghost inside Visual Studio!!!!!!

Comment: I searched for Application.Exit before.  It is not around in the entire solution.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out.  I have:

InitializeComponent();

in two places.  After removing one of them, things work the way they should.